# Content Screen Localization Google Sign-in

Tags: google-apps

I'm trying to find out how to translate the Google Sign-In screen for my application.
In the Google developer console you can enter different values for the "Consent Screen" which is the information displayed in the authorization screen while trying to log with your Google account in your web application.

There is no language options and I need to specify a different name (in other language) as well as localized Terms of use or Policy (and even the logo sometime).

How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, the end user will be presented with a localized signin and consent screen, depending on the language settings of his/her account.
I don't think it is possible to enter different URLs for policy/terms of use and/or for the name of the app. The only option i see is to enter use another domain name, with different credentials and configure a completely different consent screen.