# Localization of Google sign-in consent screen

Tags: google-openid

I know this question has already been asked here: [Content Screen Localization Google Sign-in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23698068/content-screen-localization-google-sign-in)

...but an 'AFAIK' answer was given and was the only one so I consider this unresolved.

I am trying to localize the Google sign-in consent screen to multiple locales/languages, as I can for Facebook, and am unable to find a way to do so.

Anyone know how?